# Событие обновления кода приложения

Tags: клиент-сервер, elixir

Я знаю о [событии обновления кода](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/GenServer.html#c:code_change/3) у GenServer при "горячем апдейте".

Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли подобное событие у всего приложения?

---

**UPD:**

У используемого Phoenix-приложения нашел в стандартном модуле `Application` метод `config_change`. В документации метода нет и гугл сказал, что он *deprecated*.

Однако, он вроде как еще работает. Может есть какой-то адекватный способ обработать обновление кода?